# How to access a text file in root directory from a browser in Liferay 7.2?

Tags: directory, root, liferay-7.2

I need to access a text file (ads.txt) from a browser (ex: https://mydomain/ads.txt) in the ROOT directory in Liferay 7.2.
Thx

It works fine if the file is in the html directory (https://mydomain/html/ads.txt). It works fine if the file has a jsp extension (https://mydomain/ads.jsp).